# Repeat Animation

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am working on the android app in unity and I have animation character how did some animations after entering certain text or voice so I want to let the user repeat this animation by touch the repeat button, so how can write a script for this.

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

There is a property you need to call in your respective anim file. Set repeat as infinite. It will take your animation in a loop. 
Secondly, you can also call Animation listener, which has 3 methods. The 3rd method is onAnimationEnd. In this method call startanimation.It does the same thing. 
With any of the above methods, you can call repeat animation.

Comment: sorry but I need more explanation if you don't mind.. how can I make repeat class infinite ?what is the 3 method?do you mean I call the method that play the animation?

Comment: I tried this code but there is an error on it:                                                void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 70, 50, 30), "Replay"))
        {
            var animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            animator.Play("BeginMove");
        }